# How to convert BTRFS to bcachefs on Linux Mint 21 and LMDE5?

Tags: btrfs, conversion, bcachefs

**2023-10-31, Bcachefs Merged Into The Linux 6.7 Kernel:**

- https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7
- https://web.archive.org/web/20231103095158/https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7

**Manuals:**

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/bcachefs.8.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205131951/https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/bcachefs.8.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205131951/https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish

**Mailing list:**

- http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-bcachefs

  The bcachefs management software bcachefs-tools are available by Application Management of Linux Mint 21 and actual Debian version, and consist follow related information:

  bcachefs migrate [options] device
  Migrate an existing filesystem to bcachefs

  ```
         -f fs   Root of filesystem to migrate

         --encrypted
                 Enable whole filesystem encryption (chacha20/poly1305)

         --no_passphrase
                 Don't encrypt master encryption key

         -F      Force, even if metadata file already exists
  ```

  bcachefs migrate-superblock [options] device
  Create default superblock after migrating

  ```
         -d device
                 Device to create superblock for

         -o offset
                 Offset of existing superblock
  ```

**Source:**

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205130327/https://bcachefs.org/bcachefs-principles-of-operation.pdf

**Remark:**

I am looking for a answer now, which use the bcachefs-tools, gparted or comparable tools. The existing answer, to copy the data from old ext4 partition to a new bcachefs partition, are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a better way, you can "convert" alternatively from ext4 to bcachefs on follow two ways:

Variant 1:

- take a additional hard disk
- create a bcachefs filesystem on the new one
- copy the files from old hard disk to the new one, p.e. by:

  ```
  rsync -va -AHSX source target
  ```

Variant 2 (It can happen, you will lose your data on this way...):

- do a backup of your data
- delete the old filesystem
- create the new filesystem
- restore your data from backup

Answer (score 0):

**Converting BTRFS to bcachefs are supported by:**

bcachefs-tools convert

**That can do on follow way:**

- Mount ext4 filesystem on a bcachefs supporting Linux
- convert the file system by bcachefs-tools convert
- unmount
- run migrate-superblock on the block device

**For details, see:**

- Manual: https://web.archive.org/web/20230205130327/https://bcachefs.org/bcachefs-principles-of-operation.pdf
- Samplecode:  https://evilpiepirate.org/git/ktest.git/tree/tests/bcachefs/single_device.ktest#n1061

Comment: Can you add the commands from code example please to the answer?